# What does it mean to set a dummy variable to unity?

Tags: categorical-encoding, indicator-function

I am reading a paper where a regression model is introduced. The specific model is irrelevant but it has a dummy explanatory variable, about which the authors say the following:

> *I* is a dummy variable set to unity if the individual is foreign born

I'm thrown off by the language. Does "set to unity" mean that it takes the value of 1 if individual i is foreign-born? Could you explain where the phrase "set to unity" comes from?

This is the paper: Borjas, G. J. (1987). Self-Selection and the Earnings of Immigrants (No. 2248). National Bureau of Economic Research. https://doi.org/10.3386/w2248

Comment: Correct. The variable is 1 (unity, one) if an individual is foreign-born and 0 (zero) otherwise. FWIW, the term _dummy variable_ is acceptable to some and obnoxious to others: either way, there are yet other terms, such as indicator, binary, dichotomous, Boolean, logical or quantal variable. $I$ is poor notation for a variable, in my view, as you have to look hard to see that it is not $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a fancy way of saying "set to 1".